# Norm of an integral element is integral

Tags: field-theory

Let $L / K$ be a finite field extension and let $x \in L$. Let $Norm_{L/K}(x)$ be the determinant of multiplication by x over L. Now, let us assume that $A \subset B$ are rings such that $K = Frac(A)$ and $L=Frac(B)$ and that B is integral over A. Then I am trying to show that for $ b \in B$ , the norm of b is integral over A.

I know how to do this when K is a number field, one then goes that the norm is the product of x over the different embeddings (kind of), but I am not sure how this should be done for a general field. Any hint, or something would be more than kind. Or well, I am curious whether there is any more elementary way than going through all the embeddings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The norm of an element has something to do with the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Yes, it should be the constant term,up to sign that is.

Comment: @Tedar If something is integral, what do you know about the coefficient of its min poly? :)

Comment: The follow-up question is what confuses me mostly , if you have any idea please tell me: "Let us moreover suppose that A is a polynomial ring over a field k, then $Norm_{L/K}(B) \subset A$. Why do we need the condition on a polynomial ring?

Comment: Is the fact that the constant term is the norm true in general?

Comment: @Tedar Yes. I think I need more context to comment on your excerpt. Perhaps they want to, at some point soon, use the following fact: if $A$ is finitely generated over $k$ then $B$ is a finite $A$-module (with your notation for $A$ and $B$).

Comment: Here is a link: 
http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~qliu/Book/Errata3/pages76-77.pdf
Exercise 5.14 a,b and c)! That is all the context I have. do you understand why c) requires A to be a polynomial ring?

Comment: @Tedar I think it's wanting you to use b) and the observation that $A$ is integrally closed so that things in $K$ integral over $A$ are actually in $A$.

Comment: Then I have probably misunderstood your proof that the norm is the constant term of the minimal polynomial (which I still am convinced is true, what about the case when $x \in A$? ) implies that it is integral. The coefficients of the minimal polynomial lies in A, so the norm should also be in A?

Comment: @Tedar I misread your problem by assuming that A was integrally closed (what isn't!?). You can fix my proof by replacing A by its integral closure in K. Then you get the desires result from the fact that something is integral iff it's min poly has coefficients in the base ring.

Comment: Right, thank you - so given $b \in B$, the minimal polynomial of b will not have coefficients in A? I am a bit confused, sorry!

Comment: @Tedar it's not true that something is integral (satisfies SOME monic poly with A coeffs) iff its min poly has A coeffs. This is true if A is integrally closed.

Comment: that "some part" was what confused me. Thank you so much! As one last question, you don't happen to have any reference for that the norm is the constant term of the minimal polynomial? I know how to prove it for separable galois extensions, but am not sure in general, hence asking!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11784/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-tedar)

Comment: @Tedar You just break it into its separable and purely inseparable parts. If you look at Keith Conrad's notes on Trace and Norm, they should have it.